# Worklight application builder hang

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using worklight 6.1.0.1 on Eclipse Kepler. As per the screen shot below, it hangs when I open the eclipse, with message saying "Worklight application builder". It takes forever to complete.

How do I resolve this issue ?

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to start eclipse with the -clean option on command line

Comment: Hello tik,

I started with clean option. It worked. I will keep you posted in case I get into problems again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be network related. If using a proxy server in eclipse make sure that is not enabled. This will try to route traffic through your proxy server. The other issue could be a firewall issue either locally or elsewhere. The application deployer routes out through the network to your workstation and does not use localhost. I have yet to find a way to change this setting.